# css3 webkit transition trasform translate: invalid property value?

Tags: html, css

```
-webkit-transition-property: translate
-webkit-transform:translate(-320px, 0px);
```

I have those lines in my css file but this doesn't work in chrome: if I fire up chrome developer tools and inspect css for elements whose style contains those lines i see an hazard icon that tells '**invalid property value**'

[image: webkit-transition]

what happens? is this obsolete?

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the *exact css style* in the value of `transition-property`. So what you would want is:

`-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform`

Whatever the value is needs to be a legit CSS property (exactly). Lemme know if this works! Seems good to me in Chrome.

Comment: Works ! And even on android 2.2 which made me laugh a little . But nevertheless good news :)